# Class is firing __construct on Laravel Eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I do something like this,

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->get()`;
```

constructor fires. Is there a way to avoid this?

I want to use the __contruct function only when using the new key word like this`$user = new User();`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a *Listener* **Event** ?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events

Comment: Because it's supposed to. You can check to see if it's loading a new user or an existing user by checking for a value in `$id` in the construct method.

Comment: It's a bad practice to put business logic in constructors.  When you get to designing unit tests, you'll understand why.

Comment: You're getting back one or more  of `User` how can that ever happen without them being constructed?

Answer (score 2):

Your example is very similar to what Laravel does behind the scene. When you do User::find(), you are actually asking for a new instance, either an instance of Collection or a QueryBuilder.

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

public static function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
    if (is_array($id) && empty($id)) return new Collection;

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->find($id, $columns);
}
```

You should use listeners instead.

Comment: Okay thanks. If that's how it is, then I think I just have to redesign my application.